# Make delete key also delete region in evil insert mode

Tags: key-bindings, evil

In evil insert state, I can mark a region in the buffer using the mouse. If I now press the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key (bound to the `delete-char` command) it deletes the character at the current cursor position and not the the marked region. This behavior is different from how the delete key works in normal Emacs mode where the region is killed. How can I make evil insert mode work the same way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're asking about the behavior of
<kbd>DELETE</kbd> when the region is active, or, as far as `evil`
is concerned, when you're in `evil`'s `visual` state.  It should
be enough to rebind the key in that map:

```
(define-key evil-visual-state-map [delete] #'delete-region)
```

Update: as @HakonHaegland's comment indicates, it's not exactly clear what's going on with the different states.  However, using the following keybinding seems to resolve the issue:

```
(define-key evil-insert-state-map [delete] #'evil-delete-char)
```

Comment: Actually, I am quite convinced that I am in `evil`'s `insert` state. In `visual` state I usually use `d` to delete the region. Also, if the region is not active, I would like to have the normal `delete-char` to be called, so `delete-region` will not work correctly if there is no marked region. I tried to replace your `delete-region` with `evil-delete-char` and it seems to work  fine.

Comment: @HåkonHægland: I might be misunderstanding, but I think the region is always active in `visual` state.  You can check by marking the region with your mouse as you described, then `M-: (use-region-p)` to check if the region is active.  You can also do `M-: evil-state` to determine which state you're in.

Comment: Thanks. If I try `M-: evil-state` it says `insert`. So it is as expected.

Comment: @HåkonHægland: sorry, do you mean updating it about the `evil-delete-char` function that you tried?

Comment: @HåkonHægland: done!  Still can't figure out what's going on with the different states, but I'm glad you got it working.